# Android EditText Symbol must remain at initial position

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-input-filter

I have a text field where the start symbol is $ (could be euro or pound depending on an application setting). I need to make it so that if the user clicks before the symbol nothing will happen. In other words, the selection must remain after the symbol. I tried doing something like this but it seems wrong and it gave me an error:

```
billAmount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    //other methods 

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        billAmount.setText(currencySymbol + billAmount.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

I was thinking of using an inputFilter but nothing I tried worked. I'm also not allowed to use a TextView right before the EditText.

Comment: The app just freezes and I have to force close it.

Comment: I believe your issue is that you're changing text in the afterTextChanged method. Which changes the text so afterTextChanged gets called. Which changes the text so..... Maybe make a TextView and align it to the start of the EditText. You can have the TextView just set to $ and just hang out there.

Comment: I originally had a TextView and it was working great but I was told that I had to make it in the actual EditText which is what is giving me problems.

Comment: Actually, how are you accessing billAmount? You're adding a textChangedListener to it which references it. You'd have to declare billAmount final for that.

Comment: Would you like make your life difficult? My suggestion is user a LinearLayout that contains a TextView and EditText. Just assign you currency type to TextView and work with EditText easily. You just need to assign a background to LinearLayout and assign transparent bg to EditText.

Comment: Right now it's actually just in the onCreate method. So I haven't declared it final or anything. Hessam, like I said above, unfortunately I was told I have to make it in the EditText

Comment: Seems to still have an infinite loop, I think I'm onto something where I made it so if you click on the edittext and your selection is position 0 then I set your selection to position 1. Unfortunately, you can still drag the selection thing past the point :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in your code sample, the reason you are getting an error is because, as others have said, you are calling the `setText` method inside the `afterTextChanged` method. Calling `setText` is obviously changing the text which causes `afterTextChanged` to be called again. This results in the `afterTextChanged` being called continuously until there is eventually a stack overflow.

You have two issues: 1) You want to always keep the cursor positioned after the currency symbol, and 2) You want to make sure the currency symbol is never somehow removed.

The easiest way to solve #1 is to create a subclass of `EditText` and override the `onSelectionChanged` method.

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
        super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);

        // Make sure the text's length is greater than zero.
        // Then, if the cursor is at position zero...
        if (getText().length() > 0 && selStart == 0) {
            // ...move it over to position one.
            setSelection(1, selEnd);
        }
    }
}
```

This will force the cursor to always go after the currency symbol even if the user attempts to move it before it. The check `getText().length() > 0` is to ensure that the `EditText` contains at least one character, otherwise attempting to move the cursor will result in an Exception.

As for #2, there are a couple ways to go at it. You can attempt to use some instance variables inside your TextWatcher to keep track of when the text needs to be formatted, but that won't prevent the unnecessary method calls from actually happening, and it adds some unneeded complexity. I think it would be easier to simply use an `InputFilter`, which you can specify in your extended EditText's constructor.

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

    public MyEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Set the EditText's input filter.
        setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter {
            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                        Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                // If the currency symbol is about to be replaced...
                if (dstart == 0)
                    // Add the currency symbol to the front of the source.
                    return currencySymbol + source;
                // else
                    // Return null to indicate that the change is okay.
                    return null;
            } 
        }});
    }

    // ...
}
```

In the `filter` method, the `dest` parameter represents the `EditText`'s text, and the `dstart` and `dend` parameters represent the start and end positions of the portion of the text that is about to be replaced. Since the currency symbol should always be the first character, we know it is about to be replaced if `dstart` is zero, in which case we simply return the `source` (which represents the replacement text) with the currency symbol placed in front. Otherwise, we indicate that the change is okay by returning `null`.

I tested it, and it seems to work for what you need.

On a side note, although I understand that you're not "allowed" to use a `TextView`, I think it's worth reiterating that using one would provide a much better solution to this problem. One particularly useful solution being to have a hidden `EditText` contain the raw input from the user, and having the `TextView` on top of the `EditText`. You would use a `TextWatcher` to update the `TextView` with the properly formatted input from the `EditText`.

Comment: This seems to be what I want, I got the first bit working but I'm not sure how to add the second bit with all the variables. Would I need to read from my sharedpreferences in order to get the currency symbol? It also says source is undefined I don't know why.

Comment: The problem I'm getting is that when you hit backspace and the currencySymbol is the only thing there, it highlights it and the user can type over it, I'm guessing that's what the second bit is fixing?

Comment: You can handle retrieving the currency symbol any number ways. You can add a data member called currencySymbol in your MyEditText class and add a setCurrencySymbol method to allow your app to change it. That would be the more Object-Oriented way of handling it. And yes, the second bit essentially just replaces the currency symbol in the front whenever the user attempts to delete it. Also, the first part should prevent the user from being able to highlight the currency symbol.

Comment: It prevents them from directly highlighting it but when they hit backspace on the keyboard it seems to highlight it and if they hit another character (in this case digit/decimal) it replaces the symbol.

Comment: That should not be possible if you took the steps I described in my answer (I tested it myself). Did you follow the steps I laid out? If so, did you make sure to actually add the new class to your layout?

Comment: It is working, I deviated slightly from what you did but it was a great guide, thank you. Is there a way to make the symbol update immediately when it is changed in the settings? Currently another key has to be hit.

Comment: Once you change the currencySymbol, you can manually replace the symbol in the EditText with getText(0, 1, currencySymbol) if currencySymbol is a type that implements CharSequence (such as a String), or with getText(0, 1, "" + currencySymbol) if currencySymbol is a char. If you used a setter method to change the currencySymbol in your MyEditText class, you can just add that line at the end of it and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are getting `StackOverFlowException`.  
try this
`String oldValue="";//instace variable`

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //bilamount always starts with your currency symbol
        if (s != null && s.length() == 0) {
            editText.setText("$");
            editText.setSelection(1);
        }

        if (s != null && s.length() > 0) {
            String billAmount = s.toString();
            if (!oldValue.equals(billAmount)) {//minimize unnecessary setText() method call
                oldValue= billAmount;
                editText.setText(billAmount);
                editText.setSelection(billAmount.length());
            }
        }

    }
```

**Note :** your EditText first init with your `currencySymbol` i.e.
 `billAmount.setText(currencySymbol);`

Comment: This still causes the app to crash :/

Comment: what is that exception it is throwing